# Zend_Db_Table_Abstract and MySQL COMMENTs

Tags: sql, zend-framework, mysql

I have built a query tool that enables a non-technical user to query parts of a database. I want to rename all the columns nicely. e.g.:

```
table_id` > "Table ID"
forename > "Forename"
phone > "Telephone"
```

I have put all the information into the MySQL COMMENT field as in:

```
ALTER TABLE  `table`
CHANGE `field` `field` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Nice field name'
```

I have accessed this but it seems rather heavy. Can it be accessed nicely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would overrided _setupMetadata to read in that information and populate it into the tables metat data.  Check out http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html